# Is it possible to make a range as a variable "var = k:k+number"

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

My equation in a loop is long. I would like to define a range obviously before going to substitute it into the equation line.

Here is my loop. `k` represents a range I want to use in the equation

```
    k = 0
    char_num = np.array([196, 191, 122])

    for p in xrange(3):
        # k = "k:(char_num[p]+ k)" # here is the range I which to use

        ## below is the equation which is quite cluttering. 
        H[k,:] = (H[k,:]/(2)) * \
                    (( np.sqrt((sum(W[:,k]))**2 + \
                    (4*sum((V[:,:].T*W[:,k]).T/np.dot(W[:,:],H[:,:]))) )))


        # k += char_num[p]
```

Is it possible to define k as a range as pseudocode shown?

Comment: It looks like you mean defining a *slice*, in which case: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice

Comment: `k_arr = char_num + np.arange(len(char_num))` and then iterate on `k_arr` : `for k in k_arr`?

Comment: @Divakar In that case `k` is a single number. I want to have `H[0:196,:]` for the first loop, `H[196:387,:]` for the second... So `k` has to be a range?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks. I don't know what I already used is called as slice. Can we make slice as variable then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could generate those start, stop indices with `cumsum` on `char_num` and then use those within the loop for slicing `H`, like so -

```
s = np.r_[0,char_num.cumsum()]
for i,j in zip(s[:-1], s[1:]): 
    H[i:j,:] = ...
```

Sample run -

```
In [18]: char_num = np.array([196, 191, 122])

In [19]: s = np.r_[0,char_num.cumsum()]
    ...: for i,j in zip(s[:-1], s[1:]): 
    ...:     print(i,j) # print start, stop indices
    ...:     
(0, 196)
(196, 387)
(387, 509)
```

If you actually need the range as an array for some processing other than for slicing, we can use `range(i,j)` or `np.arange(i,j)` within the loop. We can also use that range for slicing, but that would force a copy and would slow things down.

Alternatively, we can use a slice notation there, like so -

```
slice0 = slice(i,j)
H[slice0] = ... # equivalent to H[i:j], i.e. H[i:j,:]
```

Comment: It takes me a while for wrapping around your idea. It's cool. Thanks so much. I make `k = zip(s[:-1], s[1:])` and substitute into `H` as `H[k[p],:]` in `for p in xrange(3)`. Let me ask you another question. Do you think this will be slow if my `char_num` is super long? Or what is the fastest way here?

Comment: @Jan If you want to make it faster, use `s = np.concatenate(( [0], char_num.cumsum() ))`. That's the fastest way I know of on the iterating part. On the sum-reductions, i.e. RHS of `H[k,:] = `, it seems we can optimize further.